# Lock volume for writing in Windows 2003

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I am using the following code to lock volumes.

```
SafeFileHandle diskHandle = CreateFile(deviceId, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 0, IntPtr.Zero, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, IntPtr.Zero);

bool success = DeviceIoControl(diskHandle, FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME, null, 0, null, 0, out intOut, IntPtr.Zero);
```

This works for Windows 2008 and above but does not work for 2003. It does not lock the drive. The Windows Error code returned is 1008.

Comment: Upgrade the server, it is not supported any longer.

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal I think your comment could be an answer. Just add supporting documentation and you'll have +1 from me.

Comment: How do you check the error code? 1008 is a weird error to get (`ERROR_NO_TOKEN`), I'm skeptical that's the actual error code. The most likely reason for `DeviceIoControl` to fail is one of the documented failure conditions: "If the specified volume is a system volume or contains a page file, the operation fails. If there are any open files on the volume, this operation will fail."

Comment: Note that, although Microsoft no longer offers support for Windows Server 2003, [`FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME` is documented as supported by Windows Server 2003](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/aa364575), so while "upgrade the server" is an answer, it's not a comprehensive one.